# Repeat state until it doesn't change / is stable

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm trying to run a state transform repeatedly until the state doesn't change. I've [searched Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Eq+s+%3D%3E+State+s+%28%29+-%3E+State+s+%28%29) for

```
Eq s => State s () -> State s ()
```

but found nothing that looks appropriate.

How can I run a state transform repeatedly until it doesn't change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in `State`, but there's no particular benefit. Why not:

```
idempotently :: Eq a => (a -> a) -> a -> a
idempotently f a = if a' == a then a else idempotently f a' where a' = f a

idempotentlyM :: Eq s => (s -> s) -> State s ()
idempotentlyM f = modify (idempotently f)
```

If you start with a `State s ()`, you can `execState` it to get your `s -> s` out.

Of course, there's no guarantee that `f` doesn't diverge, so `idempotently f` may never terminate.

Comment: This is a fair point in the case you only need to take a peek at the state, but if you want to do some additional side-effects, as in the case of `liftIO` this will not suffice. So +1 for side-stepping the issue, but... ;)

Comment: There's no `liftIO`ing to be done with `State s ()`.

Comment: I'm generalizing to `StateT s m ()` ;)

Comment: Btw, you are computing `f a` twice, a let-binding would be nice here ;)

Answer (score 4):

You are computing the fix-point of your state transform.
But we can't use `fix` since we are in a monadic context.
So let's use a monadic fix-point combinator instead.
Enter `mfix`:

```hs
import Control.Monad (unless)
import Control.Monad.State (MonadState, StateT, get, put)
import Control.Monad.Fix (mfix)
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)

untilStable :: MonadState s m => (s -> s -> Bool) -> m a -> m ()
untilStable p = mfix $ \f st -> p <$> get <* st <*> get >>= (`unless` f)
```

I also took the liberty of generalizing your function to so that you can provide a user supplied binary predicate.

Using ghci `runState (untilStable (==) $ modify (+1)) 2` will never terminate.
But with:

```hs
comp :: StateT Int IO ()
comp = do
  s1 <- (+1) <$> get
  liftIO $ print s1
  let s2 = if s1 >= 3 then 3 else s1
  put s2
```

You get:

```hs
> runStateT (untilStable (==) comp) 0
1
2
3
4
((),3)
```

This `untilStable` can be generalized further into:

```hs
untilStable :: MonadState s m => (s -> s -> Bool) -> m a -> m a
untilStable p = mfix $ \f st -> do
  before <- get
  a <- st
  after  <- get
  if p before after then pure a else f
```

Now we have freed up what types the computations can result in.

Fix you want to implement `idempotently` with `fix`, you can do it like so:

```hs
import Data.Function (fix)

idempotently :: Eq a => (a -> a) -> a -> a
idempotently = fix $ \i f a ->
  let a' = f a
  in if a' == a then a else i f a'
```

Comment: Would `fix` even be applicable if not in a monadic context? I'm suspecting it's not quite what would be needed, as it doesn't seem to have any concept of comparing values of successive iterations.

Comment: `fix`, i.e, the non-monadic variant of `mfix` can be used to implement `idempotently`. I will update my answer to implement `idempotently` with it. By values, do you mean the value of the state, or the value of the computation? I also have to ask, why do you want to compute state-transforms until a fixed point? Is your only goal to live within `State` and not some `StateT s m a, m /= Identity`? If you want to normalize terms, consider a normalization monad based on  `Writer Any` since it is inefficient to use `(==)` at every step.

Comment: `Writer` is only efficient for lazy monoids. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @dfeuer `(<>)` for `Any` should be lazy in the second argument if the first argument is `True` but strict in all arguments if the first is `False`. `Writer [a]` will be inefficient since `(++)` has `O(n)` complexity in the first argument. But for `Any`, the complexity is always `O(1)`. We can use `Any` with `True` representing a change, and `False` representing unique normal form, we can then keep applying the rule until we get `False`.

Comment: @Centril I see how `fix` can be used... thanks! My specific case: I'm changing the stopping condition of the Sudoku solver at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/164380/34049. The state is a matrix of potential values for each cell, and when the potential values don't change between iterations, I want to stop iterating. As far as I can tell, I do just want to live in `State`.

Comment: OK, left you some comments there. The main idea behind `Writer Any` is that the part of your transformation that changes values knows if a change occurred or not. So why not let inform you of change instead of using `(==)`? We used this mechanism in our Bachelors thesis, see: https://github.com/DATX02-17-26/DATX02-17-26/blob/dev/libsrc/Norm/CompAssignment.hs and: https://github.com/DATX02-17-26/DATX02-17-26/blob/dev/libsrc/Norm/NormM.hs

Answer (score 2):

You can roll-your-own higher level recursive transform, using [`get`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.4.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Strict.html#v:get) and [`unless`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:unless)

```
untilStable :: Eq s => State s () -> State s ()
untilStable stateTransform = do
  before <- get
  stateTransform
  after <- get
  unless (before == after) $ untilStable stateTransform
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking inspiration from https://stackoverflow.com/a/44378096/1319998 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/23924238/1319998, you can do this out of `State` but using some function monad magic...

```
untilStable :: Eq a => (a -> a) -> a -> a
untilStable = until =<< ((==) =<<)
```

... extracting the `s -> s` from a state using `execState`

```
untilStable (execState stateTransformToRunRepeatedly) initialState
```

Comment: I love the impenetrability of that `untilStable` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/44381834/1319998, so keeping the iteration out of `State`, but avoiding the function monad magic with a clearer use of [`until`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:until)

```
untilStable :: Eq a => (a -> a) -> a -> a
untilStable f a = until (\w -> f w == w) f a
```

... and similarly extracting the s -> s from a state using execState

```
untilStable (execState stateTransformToRunRepeatedly) initialState
```

Point-free style isn't used, but to me it is clearer what's going on.

Also, I wonder if this reveals an inefficiency of both this and https://stackoverflow.com/a/44381834/1319998, where `f a` may be computed twice: once privately inside `until`, and once in the predicate used to test whether to stop.